# Is there a way to show choose date ranges on a graph in ssrs 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to get the graph working so that when you drill down to a certain group, you can choose if you want to look at it daily, weekly, etc.  I set parameter up with a start date and a end date, but when I run the report nothing changes.

[StartDate parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DqLJ.png)
[Series parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZDoM.png)

Comment: did you add the parameter to filter the graphs data source?

Comment: Yes, I added a start date and an end date to the parameters with the date/time selected.

Comment: yes but you also have to add the parameters to the data source of the graph, simply adding parameters and not putting it anywhere will not do anything.

Comment: post a screen shot of the parameters and how youre filtering the data source of the graph

Comment: Added screenshots. Hopefully this is what you were looking for. I am new to stack and using ssrs

Comment: I see the start date parameter. is that start date being used in the data that you are filtering? ie "select start date, enddate from dateable where start date >= @StartDateG"